# How to change the color of Searchbar

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

How can I change the color of the bottom border in Nativescript-VueJS? 
(see image)

I tried the following:

```
border-bottom-color: transparent;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to use this instead:

```
background-color: transparent;
```

Comment: Android uses a background drawable, setting the background color would remove the default bottom line.